# how to create a login liferay portlet using jsp in eclipse

Tags: liferay

I'm new to liferay, trying to create web app using liferay protlets. I'm trying to create a custom login portlet. In html file, using form action method I'm trying to call a jsp file, which is giving error. help me out. can you give suggest some tuts so tat I can learn how to design dynamic liferay protlets and to deploy in the liferay portal server.

Comment: did you happen to look at the [liferay tag-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/liferay/info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive login in liferay by

1. An AutoLogin hook http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-Portal+Properties
2. Extending authentication pipeline http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+CAS#section-Developing+a+CAS-Authenticaton+Pipeline
3. By your custom implementation http://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16008439
4. Extending Liferay itself (by EXT plugin) https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Ext+Plugin

I would suggest doing them in the order I specified, as they increase in complexity.
Please do let me know of any specific queries in these.